# Vdss, Vds(max), BVdss and Vgss, Vgs(max)

Tags: mosfet

What is the difference between those notations :

Vdss, Vds(max), BVdss

and those notations :

Vgss, Vgs(max)

According to the [comment](https://www.taiwansemi.com/assets/uploads/productcategoryfile/AN-1001_A1611.pdf) of Velvet, here the definition for BVdss :

[image]

According to the [Renesas](https://en-support.renesas.com/knowledgeBase/16981010), Vdss is

[image]

It seems that there is no difference and the definition given by Renesas is a bit missing of information ...

[Toshiba](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20180726_AKX00062.pdf?did=13414) stands for the same definition as Renesas :
[image]

What is the difference with Vdss and Vds(max) ?

Comment: This might be relevant: [Understanding Power MOSFET Parameters](https://www.taiwansemi.com/assets/uploads/productcategoryfile/AN-1001_A1611.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that unfortunately different manufacturers use slightly different notation. Usually V_DSS or V_DS(max) are the maximum allowable Drain-Source voltage according to manufacturer datasheet, the same for V_GS(max) but for Gate-Source voltage. BVdss would be the breakdown voltage and in general should be higher than the maximum allowable voltage.